# Mail.app: Moving messages out of IMAP accounts to local folders without keeping a copy in the Archive

Tags: mail.app, gmail, accounts, messages-in-icloud

I have my Mail.app set up with multiple email accounts (from different providers).

For each of these accounts, I would like to make sure that when I drag an email *out* of the respective inbox into a custom “On my Mac” folder, that it gets deleted (or ends up in the IMAP Trash folder).
However, this only works for the iCloud account. 
For Gmail accounts, unfortunately, when I drag an email out of a Gmail inbox, it ends up in the IMAP All Mail folder (under “Archive”) and not in the Trash.

See the screenshot below of my setup:
Dragging a message from **Inbox > iCloud** into **On My Mac > A Local Test Folder** deletes the message from iCloud (it doesn’t show up in either the Trash > iCloud or the Archive > iCloud folders

[image]

Dragging a message from **Inbox > Account A** into **On My Mac > A Local Test Folder** moves the message into **Archive > Account A (All Mail)**

I would like it to be either moved into the **Trash > Account A** folder (so that it eventually gets deleted from the server), or to be deleted immediately.

Here’s what I tried:  In the Gmail settings (in the browser)  under Forwarding and POP/IMAP > IMAP access I changed the setting
for **When I mark a message in IMAP as deleted:** from “Auto-Expunge on” to “Auto-Expunge off” and then changed the next option to “Move the message to the Trash” or, after that didn't work, to "Delete immediately".
Neither setting does have any effect on the behavior in Mail. The message still appears under “Archive”.

Then, in the Mail.app Preferences > Accounts > Mailbox Behaviors > for all Mailboxes (Drafts, Sent, Junk, Trash) I can choose if I want the IMAP or On My Mac version of the mailbox to be used.  See the screenshot below illustrating this option for Trash.

[image]

However, for Archive Mailbox there is no such option.  I can only choose [Gmail]/All Mail.

[image]

If there was a way to make it either use the Gmail Trash folder or the On My Mac Archive folder, that would already be of help.

Comment: make, for gmail, a rule that if anything lands in archive, delete it.

Comment: @ankiiiiiii  Could you let me know how?  In the rules, I can't find a condition "if in mailbox archive" ... ?

Comment: Sorry,I thought it would be there. The closest I can get now is that create a smart mailbox which would contain all the archived mails and you can periodically delete them. Turn off "contain messages form trash".

Comment: @ankiiiiiii Yeah, but that defeats the purpose ... and it's bizarre that iCloud works "as expected" but with other IMAP accounts it doesn't.